# Algebraic Topology: all covers of $S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I want to find all (good enough) covers of $S^1$. So I'm thinking like.

$$\pi_1{(S^1)}=\mathbb Z$$

It's abelian, that's why all subgroups (which are exactly $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$) are normal. As I understood from Hatcher book, for each normal subgroup $H$ there is one (up to isomorphism) covering space $X$ s.t. $\pi_1{(X)} = H$.

So for each $n$ there should be unique (up to isomorphism) covering space $X$ s.t. $\pi_1{(X)} = Z/nZ$. Am I right? How can I construct these spaces?

Thanks.

Comment: The subgroups of $\Bbb Z$ are $n\Bbb Z$, not $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Do you mean $n\mathbb{Z}$?  The group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a not a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$.  Also, it's not that $\pi_1(X) = H$, it's that if $p:X\rightarrow S^1$ is the projection, that $p_\ast(\pi_1(X)) = H$.

Comment: @Arthur, ye, stupid me. You're right.

Comment: @JasonDeVito, but $p_{*}$ is injection, right? So it's the same in fact.

Comment: **Hint** The map $z \mapsto z^n$ is an $n$-fold cover $S^1 \to S^1$.

Comment: For covering spaces, yes, $p_\ast$ is an injection.  But as Travis says, $X = S^1$ whenever $n\neq 0$.  So, you'd be writing $\pi_1(S^1) = H\subsetneq \pi_1(S^1)$, which looks contradictory.  But you would mean $p_\ast(\pi_1(S^1)) = H \subsetneq \pi_1(S^1)$ which is fine.

Comment: @Travis, thank you, got it! Then the projection of $1 \in \pi_1 (X)$ is $n \in \pi_1 (S^1)$.

Comment: One last thing:  if $n = 0$, then Travis's map is *not* a covering map.  But $0\mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$.  So what is $X$ if $n = 0$?

Comment: @JasonDeVito, it's just R, the universal covering. Got it, thank you!

Comment: @JasonDeVito You're right, I meant for $n \neq 0$, of course.